# Trying to replace punctuation that doesn't appear at beginning or end of string with sed

Tags: bash, sed

```
sed -i '/^'/! /$'/! s/'/\''/g' binfile.new
```

The purpose of this code is that if I have the following line:

```
'Here is Jay's House'
```

It will convert it to

```
'Here is Jay''s House'
```

I can't figure out the syntax -- any assistance?

Comment: Do we know for sure that there will be `'` at the beginning and the end of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the example input, much the easiest technique is:

```
sed -e "s/'/''/g" -e "s/^''/'/" -e "s/''$/'/"
```

Replace every single quote by two single quotes; replace the leading pair by one single quote; replace the trailing pair by one single quote.

This assumes that the string as a whole starts at the beginning and ends at the end of a line.  If it only covers part of the line, you have to work a lot harder, but the question should show realistic inputs and outputs, please.

```
sed -e "s/'/''/g" -e "s/^\([^']*\)''/\1'/" -e "s/''\([^']*\)$/'\1/"
```

Replace every single quote by two single quotes.  Capture zero or more non-quotes at the start of the line followed by two single quotes; replace it with what was captured plus one single quote.  Capture two single quotes followed by zero or more non-quotes at the end of the line; replace it with one single quote and what was captured.

Normally, I use single quotes around the regexes.  However, when you have single quotes in the regex (and not double quotes), then it becomes simpler to use double quotes around the regex, but you have to worry about what the shell will do to the double quoted regex.  This time, there isn't a problem; it will not always be so simple.  In case of doubt, use single quotes around the regex, and the character sequence `'\''` to embed a single quote into the middle of the string:

```
sed -e 's/'\''/'\'''\''/g' -e 's/^\([^'\'']*\)'\'''\''/\1'\''/' -e 's/'\'''\''\([^'\'']*\)$/'\''\1/'
```

(I have a program that generated that output from the version with the double quotes.  A human might optimize it when there are two adjacent single quotes; this outputs two unnecessary single quotes when that happens.)

Comment: If you are using single quotes it's far clearer to just put it in a file.

Answer (score 0):

With the sed script in a separate file: assuming we know that there will be `'` at both ends of the string:

```
$ sed -rf sedscr <<< "'Here is Jay's House'"
'Here is Jay''s House'
```

where `sedscr` is

```
s/^'(.*)'$/\1/  # Extract part between single quotes
s/'/''/g        # Replace all single quotes with two single quotes
s/(.*)/'\1'/    # Add single quotes at beginning and end back
```

For a single quoted string in the middle of text:

```
# Copy pattern space to hold space
h

# Extract substring between single quotes
s/[^']*'(.*)'[^']*/\1/

# Replace single quote with two each
s/'/''/g

# Append hold space to pattern space
G

# Replace part between single quotes
s/(.*)\n([^']*').*('[^']*).*$/\2\1\3/
```

with results like

```
$ sed -rf sedscr.sed <<< "Text before 'Here is Jay's House' text after"
Text before 'Here is Jay''s House' text after
```